# Vlookup to a table on a different user selected file VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to enter a Vlookup formula into Column S of a worksheet named "FY_16".  I need the user to select the file (which changes each month) that the "table array" for the formula is in.

Each month the file changes, but the column I want to look up to will always be the same - Column W (but have varying number of rows).  The "table array" that the formula will look up to is part of a table.

My code at this point is below:

```
Private Function UseFileDialogOpen()
MsgBox ("When the browse window opens: please select the previous months published FY16 Consulting SKU File")

Dim myString As String
' Open the file dialog
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Show
If .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
    myString = .SelectedItems(1)
    'MsgBox myString
    UseFileDialogOpen = myString
Else
    MsgBox ("Failed to properly open file")
    myString = "fail"
    UseFileDialogOpen = myString
End If
End With
End Function

Sub Vlookup
Dim filelocation 'as what?????

filelocation = UseFileDialogOpen()


Worksheets("FY_16").Range("T2:T" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-3], [" & myString & "] PA Rev!R1C23:R900000C23,1,false)"
```

My issue occurs on the final line of code.  I receive a "run time error 1004 : application defined or object defined" message.

I know my syntax is incorrect for the vlookup in a few ways.  I am not sure the "& myString & " is correct, perhaps this should be "filelocation"?

I also don't believe R1C1 can be used to name a range like I have in the vlookup.  I typically would use

```
  .Range(Cells(2,23), Cells(90000,23))
```

But I am not sure how to use that with the variable that holds the selected file name.

Also, I am using the 90000 row because this will go past my data each month (usually row count is around 75000).  I would much rather find the exact row number but I don't believe this can be done without opening the "target file" selected by the user.  If there is a way to achieve this, please offer any advice!

I am wondering if there is a way to use the Table Names to set the table array?

The non-VBA vlookup is as follows:

```
=VLOOKUP(Q2,'TargetFile.xlsb'!REV[[#All],[Net New Match]],1,FALSE)
```

TargetFile is the user selected file
REV is the worksheet the table array is on
Net New Match is the column I want to look up to (the entire column)

I played around with using these table names but couldn't get the syntax correct (possibly because the rest of the formula code is incorrect also).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Let me know if any clarification is needed.

Mike

Comment: If you are trying to do a `VLOOKUP` on a closed workbook, the address will need to be something that looks like `'C:\Temp\[Book2.xlsx]PA Rev'!R1C23:R900000C23`.  That won't be the same format that comes from the `UseFileDialogOpen` function.  (And you can't use `myString` because you defined that to be local to `UseFileDialogOpen` - but you can use `filelocation` which you have used to store the result from `UseFileDialogOpen`.  But, as I said, it won't be in the right format anyway.)

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for the input !  Instead of using the `UseFileDialogOpen` is there another option that would return the user selected file in the `'C:\Temp\[Book2....` format which could then be stored and used in the `Vlookup` formula?

Comment: @YowE3K I tested in the Immediate window and the `filelocation` is returning a "value' in the `C:\Users\...` format.  My Formula is now:
`Worksheets("FY_16").Range("T2:T" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-3], [" & fileLocation & "] PA Rev!R1C23:R90000C23,1,false)"` and this returns a Run-time 1004 error -- suggestions?

Comment: **Completely untested**, but `... = "=vlookup(RC[-3], '" & Left(fileLocation, InStrRev(fileLocation, "\")) & "[" & Mid(fileLocation, InStrRev(fileLocation, "\") + 1) & "]PA Rev'!R1C23:R90000C23,1,false)"` might work.

Comment: Wait - I think I missed something, but where is `LastRow` being declared?

Comment: Use an inputbox after they open the file to return a variant & convert it to a range: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx

Comment: @BruceWayne Opps! Sorry, The `LastRow` is properly declared but I accidentally did not include it on the code I pasted in the question.

Comment: @YowE3K The untested code you posted worked !

Comment: @Absinthe Thank you for the link - I'm not sure I am understanding completely where that would be be used / what it would replace?  Apologies if I am missing something simple !

Comment: @RugsKid Sorry I think I misread your post. I just tried YowE3K's solution though & it works well.

Comment: @Absinthe No worries !  Thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for accessing a range in an unopened workbook would be something that looks like `'C:\Temp\[Book2.xlsx]PA Rev'!R1C23:R900000C23`. That won't be the same format that comes from the `UseFileDialogOpen` function.

You also can't use `myString` within your `Vlookup` subroutine because you defined that variable to be local to `UseFileDialogOpen` - but you can use `filelocation` which you have used to store the result from `UseFileDialogOpen`. But, as I said, it won't be in the right format anyway, so it will require a bit of reformatting.

The following command should do the necessary reformatting:

```
Worksheets("FY_16").Range("T2:T" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = _
     "=vlookup(RC[-3],'" & Left(fileLocation, InStrRev(fileLocation, "\")) & _
     "[" & Mid(fileLocation, InStrRev(fileLocation, "\") + 1) & _
     "]PA Rev'!R1C23:R90000C23,1,false)"
```